# Using different compare functions for sorting and duplicate checking with std::set

Tags: c++, set, comparator

Given the following custom type

```
struct custom_type {
    int c[5];
    float w;
}
```

can I somehow define a `std::set<custom_type>` such that the ordering among elements inside the set is done by comparing the `.w` field but two elements are considered equivalent if they match on the `.c` field?

I know that there is usually one compare function used for ordering and two elements are equivalent if `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`, but maybe there's a work-around.

Comment: Equivalence is defined via `operator==` while order relationships are defined by `operator<`

Comment: @Vivick `std::set` always uses less (or operator<) for comparison and test for quality.  Equals can be done by `!(a < b || b < a)` for example.

Comment: Yep, that's what http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set says

Comment: So you want `{{1,2,3,4,5}, 1.0} < {{2,3,4,5,6}, 2.0} < {{1,2,3,4,5}, 3.0}` but the first and third elements are equivalent? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The compare function must establish a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). `std::set` needs the order and a working `operator <` to find an element in O(log(N)) time complexity.

As an example, let's say you have a set ( 1a, 3b, 5c, 7d, 9e, 11f ). The number is your `float w` for ordering, and the letter represents `int c[5]` for equality. You want to find 5f. According to your definition, 5f equals 11f. If `std::set` has already tested the elements 3b and 7d, it will expect 5f to be between them, and will not search somewhere else. Now, if 5c does not compare equal to 5f, `std::set` will never find the element.

---

If you can make sure that when `int c[5]` is equal, `float w` is also equal, you could use a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) which is ordered by `w`. [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/equal_range) returns two iterators which you can use to find the element that also matches `c`